# How to select the text behind an element?

Tags: bash, xpath, xmllint

I have the following `xmllint` example selecting an element:

```
$ curl -s http://lists.opencsw.org/pipermail/users/2015-January/date.html |
xmllint --html --xpath '/html/body/p/b[contains(., "Messages:")]' -
<b>Messages:</b>
```

Behind the bold element is the number of messages I am interested in. It is shown, when I use the `parent` axis:

```
$ curl -s http://lists.opencsw.org/pipermail/users/2015-January/date.html |
xmllint --html --xpath '/html/body/p/b[contains(., "Messages:")]/parent::*' -
<p><b>Starting:</b> <i>Thu Jan  1 23:17:09 CET 2015</i><br><b>Ending:</b> <i>Sat Jan 31 14:51:07 CET 2015</i><br><b>Messages:</b> 28</p>
```

I thought that the `following-sibling` axis might give me exactly this number, but it does not do so:

```
$ curl -s http://lists.opencsw.org/pipermail/users/2015-January/date.html |
xmllint --html --xpath '/html/body/p/b[contains(., "Messages:")]/following-sibling::*' -
XPath set is empty
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This text node you are after is indeed a following sibling, but it's a *text* node, not an element node. An expression like

```
following-sibling::*
```

Only looks for following siblings that are *elements*. To match text nodes, use `text()`:

```
$ curl -s http://lists.opencsw.org/pipermail/users/2015-January/date.html |
xmllint --html --xpath '/html/body/p/b[contains(., "Messages:")]/following-sibling::text()'
```

The commands above do not work on my computer, using bash on Mac OS X - but I trust it works for you. If I first save the result from `curl` and then use

```
$ xmllint example.html --html --xpath '/html/body/p/b[contains(., "Messages:")]/following-sibling::text()'
```

The result is `_28`. That's not really an underscore, but a whitespace that I wanted to point to. To remove the leading whitespace, use

```
$ xmllint example.html --html --xpath 'normalize-space(/html/body/p/b[contains(., "Messages:")]/following-sibling::text())'
```

---

And no, using regex is not really an option.